# is it a good idea to save primary keys in my front-end to use them after to send to my server to make some database operations?

Tags: java, web-applications, web-frontend

I want to put you into context. I have a java web application where I am using the following.

- mybatis to access database
- bootstrap as framework css
- datatable js
- jquery to make ajax call to my server

Also I have two HTML(updateDriver.html, assignCarToDriver.html) and three entities in my database.

- driver
- car
- driver_car

So I have two scenarios.

- First one is about making an update to driver entity in updateCar.html
- Second one is to assign a car or cars to a driver in assignCarToDriver.html.

As you can see the database relationship between my two entities is many-to-may, so my database looks like this.

| driver |---|driver_car|---| car |

**In the first scenario**, In the first html(updateDriver.html), this steps going to happen.

1. The server sends the driver entity to my front-end whith its database attributes like primary key, name, last name, age.
2. I would show this attributes on my html, but not showing primary key (this one I would put into hidden input text)

So when the user press "update" buttton on my html, I would get the values through jquery and send them to my server to make the update in my database, my question comes here, is it good approach to hide the primary key into hidden input text? and if it isn't, what other ways exist to achieve this?

**In the second scenario**, In sencod html (assignCarToDriver.html) has a combo that shows all enable drivers, an input text where the user have to write the car license plate and a table (datatable js) where cars will be showed. So imagine this. I select the first driver showed in the combo, then I put the car license plate in my input text, I press "search" button, so this steps going to happen.

1. The server sends me the car entity with its attributes like primary key, model, color to front-end
2. So I would show the car attributes on my table(datatable js), but not showing primerary key (I would make column invisible)

So when the user press "Assign" button I would get the combo value, the table records and then I would send them to my server, my question comes here, In this case, is it a good approach to get entities, put them on a table (datatable js) and hide the column where primary key is showed to send them to my server to can make the assign operation? and if it isn't, what other ways exist to achieve this?

As you can see, I think it is bad practice to have primary keys in my front-end, but I may be wrong.

I hope my explanation was clear and I'm so sorry if I wrote too much, but I'm new making java web application and I really want to develop systems respecting good approachs and best practices, I hope you can help me. In advance I appreciate your help.

Comment: This post has a lot of text and needs to be broken up. Really hard to follow clearly and you kind of jump around a bit. Please break it up into sections and consider using a list in some spots where applicable.

Comment: perfectly fine, but if I were you, I will put the primary key as the radiobutton values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfectly fine. However,instead of hiding the primary key ( the entity's id ) in column, you should put it as radio button values.